# How to copy image of used portion of boot HD to smaller replacement SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, disk-image

I bought a 80gb Intel SSD to be my primary boot and system disk. I have trimmed my current primary (500gb RAID1) down to 60gb. I want to now image or copy and make the SSD my primary. The software  that Intel advertised with this SSD (the reason I thought this would be easy), Intel Data Migration Software powerd by Acronis, just fails with a very helpfull "operation failed". I tried DriveSnapShot, but I don't see how to have it make an image that is just the 60gb used of the 500gb drive. It makes a full 500gb image.

Suggestions? Am I being naive to think I can do this without a full reinstall of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to image that thing and get it onto a smaller disk, try [ShadowProtect](http://www.storagecraft.com/), its good for 30 days and should get you where you need to be for free.

EDIT: I'm not affiliated with the product, I've just used it a ton and its slick.

Comment: thx... will try that. I paid for HD Clone basic, (free won't downsize) but the system would not recognize it as a boot disk.

Comment: no joy.... ShadowProtect says not enough free space on the destination even though I told th ebackup to not backup 'free space'.